# NoSuchMethodError while using GoogleAnalytics and proguard

Tags: google-analytics, proguard

I am using Google Analytics and proguard in my application.
Application working fine without proguard enabled. 
But when I am creating signed Apk with Proguard enabled and GoogleAnalytics then I am getting following error.

I googled a lot but couldn't find solution. Please help

GoogleAnalytics class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

        AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(this);
        AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);


    }

    public synchronized Tracker getGoogleAnalyticsTracker() {
        AnalyticsTrackers analyticsTrackers = AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance();

        return analyticsTrackers.get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
    }

    /***
     * Tracking screen view
     *
     * @param screenName screen name to be displayed on GA dashboard
     */
    public void trackScreenView(String screenName) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

        // Set screen name.
        t.setScreenName(screenName);

        // Send a screen view.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).dispatchLocalHits();
    }

    /***
     * Tracking exception
     *
     * @param e exception to be tracked
     */
    public void trackException(Exception e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

            t.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
                            .setDescription(
                                    new StandardExceptionParser(this, null)
                                            .getDescription(Thread.currentThread().getName(), e))
                            .setFatal(false)
                            .build()
            );
        }
    }

    /***
     * Tracking event
     *
     * @param category event category
     * @param action   action of the event
     * @param label    label
     */
    public void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

        // Build and send an Event.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category).setAction(action).setLabel(label).build());
    }
```

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method j()I in class
>   Landroid/content/res/XmlResourceParser; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser' appears in
>   /system/framework/framework.jar)
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzp.zzS(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics.newTracker(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at com.xxxx.xxx.googleAnalytics.a.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.xxx.xxx.googleAnalytics.MyApplication.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

For whatever unknown reason, we had to add this:

```
-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *;}
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
```

Answer (score 1):

From your error log it seems that interface j() cannot be found.

But if this is the error of google library this will help you

**keep class com.google.** {*;}**

**-keepclassmembers class com.google.** {*;}**

if you are still getting error please use this

**-dontwarn com.google**